# Time Function Syntax

Tags: c++, c, syntax, time, readability

Why is the `time` function usually used like this:

```
time_t currentTime;
currentTime = time( NULL );
```

instead of this:

```
time_t currentTime;
time( &currentTime );
```

Is the first method used more just because it is arguably more readable? Or is there another reason?

Thanks.

Edit: Also, why was the `time` function even designed this way? Why have two ways to set the variable?

Comment: The second example should be `time (&currentTime);`

Comment: I think the design question in your edit is the more interesting question. Is (or was) there an actual rationale, or is it just some accident?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It always seems to make more sense to return a value from a function than pass a paramter that is changed.

This might be because we learned on languages where functions and subroutines were different, don't know about these youngsters today.

Comment: @Matt what? could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jay - In e.g. Python where values (of numbers) are immutable, `def f(i): return i + 1` / `i = 0; i = f(i)` works, but `def g(i): i += 1` / `i = 0; f(i)` doesn't (in fact there's no really good way that I can think of to make it work).

Answer (score 1):

Of course only K&R probably know the true answer, but my suspect is that is just an "incident" because of historical implementation reasons. For example may be the design of this function started as `void time(time_t*)` because simply wasn't possible in some form of pre-ansi C to return a value of type `time_t` and only later evolved in a value-returning function.

If this is the explanation then the reason for keeping the parameter anyway is of course backward compatibility with existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The most common format is actually `time_t currentTime = time( NULL );`

This is shorter, and doesn't leave the `currentTime` variable uninitialized. The parameter is a historic accident and has no use.

Answer (score -1):

The timer parameter is a pointer to an object of type time_t, where the time value is stored.
Alternativelly, this parameter can be a null pointer, in which case the parameter is not used, but a time_t object is still returned by the function.

So you don't need to create a time_t object.

Comment: I know how the `time` function works, that is not the question. As far as your last sentence, do you mean that you don't have to create a `time_t` object on an earlier line? Because you still have to have create a `time_t` object...

Comment: you first code block has the unnecessary line `time_t currentTime;`. The `time( NULL )` function creates a time_t object anyway, I believe, so you don't need to create your own (you don't use it). EDIT: the timer parameter is the only parameter of the time function

Comment: 1. you don't need the first line of your first example. 2. I said "The timer parameter is a pointer..." before. "timer parameter" refers to the parameter of the `time` function

Comment: 1. yes, on my first example I could, if I was creating the variable at that time, do it like this: `time_t currentTime = time ( NULL )`. but I don't believe that is why people use the first method, instead of the second. 2. yeah, I get that, but what is your point?